# StackDriver filter works in UI, not with gcloud

Tags: gcloud, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I have the following filter in stackdriver at https://console.cloud.google.com/

```
resource.type="cloud_dataproc_cluster"
jsonPayload.application="application_1580294281653_0029"
```

and it returns lots of log records:
[image]

however the same filter when using gcloud returns nothing:
`gcloud logging read    "resource.type=\"cloud_dataproc_cluster\" AND jsonPayload.application=\"application_1580294281653_0029\""    --format="csv(timestamp,severity,jsonPayload.message)"`

I have no idea why. To me they look the same so they should return the same. I'm clearly missing something simple, anyone know what?

Answer (score 1):

ignore this, user error. I forgot to specify the project in my `gcloud` command. doh.